# Developer Professional Edition Org Signup

Tags: appexchange, developer, professional-edition

Can someone point me to where you sign up for a Developer Professional Edition Org so I can test my package in PE.  I used to know where you did this before they changed things around.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[Signup process](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Partner_Development_&_Test_Environments)

From [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/isv1_intro_quickstart.htm)

Step 1: Sign up for the Partner Program
The first step is to sign up for the AppExchange Partner Program.

In your browser, go to https://partners.salesforce.com and click Join Now.
Note
The signup process may vary according to the region or country. Please follow the instructions provided during signup.

Fill in the fields about you and your company.
Select the first option: Independent Software Vendor (ISV).
Click Submit Registration.
In a moment you’ll receive a confirmation, followed by an email welcoming you the AppExchange Partner Program and including login credentials. You’ll receive a separate email with login credentials for the Partner Portal.

Congratulations, you're now part of the Salesforce ISV Partner Program! Click the link to the Partner Community (https://partners.salesforce.com) and log in. Bookmark this page; you'll be using it a lot.

Step 2: Generate Development and Test Environments
In order to build and sell apps on the Force.com platform, you need different environments for different tasks. We call these environments organizations, or orgs for short. Getting the necessary orgs is easy through the Partner Portal. The first org you need is a Partner Developer Edition organization, which is where you'll do your development and eventually package your application. If you already have a Developer Edition organization, you should still sign up for Partner Developer Edition, because it allows more data storage, licenses, and users.

You should already be logged in to the Partner Portal. If not, click your bookmark and log in now.
In the Partner Portal, in the Quick Links section, click Create a Test Org.
Generate an Org
Click Create a Test Org
In the Edition drop-down box, choose Partner Developer Edition. For simplicity, we'll refer to this as your dev org from now on.
Select the check box to agree to the terms and then click Submit. In a few moments you'll get an email with a login link.
While you're waiting for that email you can save some time by generating other orgs you'll need. Next you'll sign up for a test org, which is used to test the app you develop. In the Quick Links area, click Create a Test Org again, but this time choose Enterprise/Platform Edition. For simplicity, we'll refer to this as your test org from now on.
Shortly, you'll receive emails that will prompt you to log in and change your password for your dev and test orgs. Click the link, change your password, and create a password question and answer.

Step 3: Get a Business Org
In the previous step, you got orgs specifically for development and testing. In order to publish your app and manage your app licenses, you'll need an organization designed specifically for that purpose. In this step you log a case in the Partner Community to have an ISV CRM Edition provisioned for you. Think of this as your “business org” as it will be used to publish and manage the sales and distribution of your app.

Note
This feature is available to eligible partners. For more information on the Partner Program, including eligibility requirements, please visit us at www.salesforce.com/partners.

In the Partner Community, under the Support tab, click New Case.
For the first category, choose Orders and Contracts.
For the second category, choose Request ISV Business Org.
In the Subject field, enter Need ISV CRM.
In the Description field, tell us if you have an existing org or if you need a new one. If you have an existing Salesforce org, you can provide the Org ID in the Description field and two additional CRM licenses will be added to your org. If you don't have an existing org, we'll provide a new one for you. In either case, make sure to enter your business address and then click Submit Case.
Shortly, you'll receive another email prompting you to log in and change your password. Do that, and then bookmark the page as before.

Step 4: Edit Your Publisher Listing
In this step, you log in to the AppExchange and provide information about your company.

You should still be logged in to your business org. In the upper right corner, click Add AppExchange Apps.
In the upper right corner, click Login or Register.
On the login page, use your username and password for your business org.
Click the Publishing tab.
Click Your Provider Profile.
Fill out the information in the Provider Profile and then click Save.